# What Internet protocol is used by google play store in backgroud for searching and downloading?

Tags: android, networking, android-networking

I know this is not programming question but i really want to know what internet protocol is used by google play store, as of know i am thinking they are using HTTPS but i am not sure about whether they used it for searching or downloading, i searched but not find satisfactory answer.

I also how i will protocol used by different apps installed in android.

I tried to find different protocol used by different application and i sort of find about some apps like Whatsapp, FB etc but i need to find about mostly used protocol.

This information is need for my literature survey for my research.

Comment: I would ask this kind of question on http://android.stackexchange.com. If you want to find out. Use Wireshark ]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because explaining how someone's application works is not on-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I would ask this kind of question on http://android.stackexchange.com more than here. If you want to find it out directly, use Wireshark or Charles (OS X). With one of these tool, you'll be able to see all out outcoming and incoming connections of your android device (and then able to study the different protocols).

But the standard in the industry is definitely HTTPS and all the companies, even the small startups use HTTPS.

Comment: The question is about the internet protocol not how you search something in the store... It's not an implementation question; that's why it doesn't belong on SO.